# Passing Data Between

Tags: ios, objective-c, didselectrowatindexpath

I have two ViewControllers conected by a segue, the first is **Sub View** and the second is **Sub Tabela**
I want to **pass a value from the selected row in that table from my first view controller to my second view controller, so i can define his title**.
Here is the code.

SubView.m (My first ViewController)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // _vinhoArray is the array that I populate the TableView
    NSString *selectedRow = [_vinhoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Sub Tabela is the name of Second View
    SubTabela *subTabela = [[SubTabela alloc] init];
    // tituloTabela is a NSString in my Second View
    subTabela.tituloTabela = linhaSelecionada;

    // Here i get the Right value
    NSLog(@"value %@", subTabela.tituloTabela);

}
```

SubTabela.h (My second ViewController)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tituloTabela;
```

SubTabela.m

```
@synthesize tituloTabela;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = tituloTabela;

    // Here i get the a Null value
    NSLog(@"value %@", tituloTabela);

}
```

Please Help!

Comment: where is the code for opening the screen? its very important as I think I see your error

Comment: The screen is opening by a segue.
Sorry if i dont understand, i'm very new in the development.

Comment: Yes I no your using a segue but you haven't added the code that calls the segue into your question

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin so when and how i call this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your passing your data in correctly, it looks as though you are creating an object inside your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and passing the data into that, then discarding this object. What you need to do is call this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:<#(NSString *)#> sender:self];
```

to change the screen and then pass the data like this is the `prepareForSegue` callback

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SubTabela *vc = (SubTabela *)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.tituloTabela = linhaSelecionada;
}
```

Comment: But I don't to pass the value inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?
How i can't get the value from the selected row?

Comment: @DiegoRodrigues but your not passing the data inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you create a variable called `subTabela`, you set the data then you don't use that object again, so its not getting used anywhere. Then when you call the segue it creates that viewController again without the data you've set on the first one. You need to create a variable outside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method , call the segue in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` callback and pass the data as i've shown.

Comment: @DiegoRodrigues just because you create `subTabela` doesn't mean anything you do to it affects all `subTabela`'s in your app. You can have many of the same class and pass different values into them using the above

Comment: If a call the method `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:<#(NSString *)#> sender:self];` inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`
I get this error and my navigation bar is currupted.
**2014-01-20 15:33:36.885 Prototipo[2001:70b] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2014-01-20 15:33:37.247 Prototipo[2001:70b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.**

Comment: @DiegoRodrigues the error is saying your trying to push multiple times. Did you leave in your other call to trigger the segue? This is why I asked you twice to edit your question and show that part of your code!  take out any other call to push the segue and it should be fine